# can't get my for loop to work

Tags: c#, for-loop, increment, unity-game-engine

I'm having trouble getting my for loop to work. I can either get it to work once, or without a limit. I'm trying to get coins to instantiate up to 3 times. I don't think the for loop itself is wrong, but the structure somewhere is. The loop is in the Looted function.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class corpseKicked : MonoBehaviour {

private Rigidbody2D rb;
private Animator anim;
public GameObject coinPrefab;
public Transform coinSpawn;
private bool kicked = false;
public float timer = 2f;
public GameObject deathFlamePrefab;
private bool flamer;
private bool pay = false;
private bool broke = false;

void Start ()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{
    Looted ();
}

public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (!kicked && other.gameObject.tag == "kickIndicator") {
        kicked = true;
        transform.Translate (0.0f, .05f, 0.0f);
    }
}

public void Looted ()
{
    if (!pay && kicked) {

        pay = true;
        Instantiate (coinPrefab, coinSpawn.position, coinSpawn.rotation);
        kicked = false;
        pay = false;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)

            Debug.Log ("$$$$$$$$$");
    }
}
```

Comment: `i >= 3;` should be `i <= 3;`. It's "continue while this is true", not "stop when this is true".

Comment: oh right. sry i forgot to put that back. I got to a point where i was trying random combinations. thanks

Comment: Don't change your question to show the corrected source code. This makes it worthless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public GameObject deathFlamePrefab;
private bool flamer;
private bool pay = false;
private bool broke = false;
private int kickedCount = 0;

void Start ()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{
    Looted ();
}

public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (!kicked && other.gameObject.tag == "kickIndicator") {
        kicked = true;
        transform.Translate (0.0f, .05f, 0.0f);
    }
}

public void Looted ()
{
    if (!pay && kicked) {

        pay = true;

        kicked = false;

        if (kickedCount < 3)
        {
           Instantiate (coinPrefab, coinSpawn.position, coinSpawn.rotation);
           kickedCount++;
        }
        pay = false;
    }
}
```

Am uncertain as to what `pay` does but you may need to place that within the `if` statement

Comment: it's still instantiating over 3 times. Basically, the player kicks a corpse and a coin comes out. I want the player to not be able to collect anymore coins from the body after the player has kicked the corpse 3 times.

Comment: So 1 coin per kick?

Comment: My bad, I forgot to increment kickedCount

Comment: OHHHHhhhhhhh! I would have never figured that out. Thanks dude you're the man. I assumed I needed a for loop and I don't have a lot experience when it comes to loops anyway.

Comment: No problem.  Glad you got it!

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
public void Looted ()
{
    if (!pay && kicked) {

        pay = true;
        Instantiate (coinPrefab, coinSpawn.position, coinSpawn.rotation);
        kicked = false;
        pay = false;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        {    
            Debug.Log ("$$$$$$$$$");
        }
    }
}
```

See the difference in the `for` condition.  Think of it as "do this loop as long as this condition is true."  Since `i` starts at one and is incremented at the end of the statement `i++`, this will run three times as you expect.

It's more common and idiomatic though to say

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3, i++)
```

unless there's a special reason you need to count starting at 1.

Comment: good to know. It's still doing it though. It's still instantiating the coins every time pay is true. Thanks for the info though